# How can i set Product Status Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have set `catalog_product_save_after` for the tracking the status of product, but it's run every time when we save the product without change any status of it. can anyone please suggest me the better way to call it only if we change product status.

thank in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event for status change, but you can still use `catalog_product_save_after` and make your code run only when something changes.
Your code should look something like this:

```
public function checkStatus($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $newStatus = $product->getStatus();
    $oldStatus = $product->getOrigData('status');
    if ($newStatus != $oldStatus) {
        //your functionality here
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, working fine for me. Great Marius! thanks for it.